# Is a multiple argument constructor ever useful over a single tuple argument constructor?

Tags: ocaml

For example, is there ever a case where a type like `type x = A of int * int` is better than `type y = B of (int * int)`? And what does this distinction actually mean?

---

The places I see that `x` is worse is trying to match the "argument" of the constructor (seems like it's two arguments, but its printed as one tuple) as a tuple:

```ml
type x = A of int * int
type y = B of (int * int)
              
let v = (1, 1)
(* let a = A v  (* Doesn't work *) *)
let b = B v  (* Works *)

(* let f = function
| A v -> v  (* Doesn't work *) *)
let g = function
| B v -> v  (* Works *)
```

So it looks like it only places restrictions to have multiple arguments, even though they have the same representation?

Comment: Adding to the language the convenience to extract a tuple from a constructor and back has been proposed several times, see [this PR](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/284). It is not consensual. The main issue is that extracting a tuple via pattern-matching, as in `fun (A v) -> v`, would, unexpectedly, allocate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They don't have the same representation. The representation with the tuple takes more memory and it requires two objects rather than one.

A constructed value is represented by a header word, followed by one word for each value.

So `A (x, y)` is represented by 3 words: header, `x`, `y`.

And `B ((x, y))` is represented by 2 words: header, tuple.
Then tuple is represented by 3 words: header, `x`, `y`

Total for `A` is 3 words. Total for `B` is 5 words. Plus `B` has two objects to manage for GC and so on. Accessing the x component of `A` takes one indirection and for `B` it takes two indirections.

If you mean `A (x, y)` and `B (x, y)` look the same syntactically, that's true. It's definitely a little bit strange. But there is a point to having them be different internally (as I tried to show).

Comment: Ah so there is a difference that's not syntatic! I've found `Obj.reachable_words (Obj.repr (A (1, 1))) = 3` and `Obj.reachable_words (Obj.repr (B (1, 1))) = 5`. Thanks, I guess I won't be changing `A of t * t` to `A of (t * t)` everywhere

Comment: Here is another way to view this which is perhaps more satisfying: any “tuple” (a memory block, really) has a tag. So the bare tuple syntax `(1,2)` is in fact a shorthand for `Tuple(1,2)` where `Tuple` is a predefined tag. With that imaginary syntax, the difference between `A(x, y)` and `B( Tuple(x, y) )` is clear, as is the fact that you cannot turn a `A`-tagged tuple to a `Tuple`-tagged tuple for free (unless using unsafe features).